# When did redstone dust change its redirection behavior with torches?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone, version-differences

In old versions of minecraft, redstone dust will redirect itself to the direction of a torch if the dust is placed on a block with a torch. When did this behavior change? I believe the change happened after Beta 1.7?

Here's a picture

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior was changed with Beta 1.9 Prerelease 6. Prerelease 5 still has the old behavior.

Note the naming confusion: the prerelease names have "Beta 1.9" in name, but there was never a Beta 1.9 release - the full release name was Minecraft 1.0.

[image]

[image]